# Cannot create tracker / session is not initialized on Sitecore 9

Tags: xdb, tracking

I'm getting the following error while attempting to test some analytics functionality on Sitecore 9:

```
9528 15:23:51 ERROR Cannot create tracker.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: session is not initialized
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.HttpSessionContextManager.GetSession()
```

I am simply accessing the default Sitecore Home item. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am having the same problem as well.

Comment: @JovitMayo I self-answered below, my issue was related to the server role that I was using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that you are not running in the `ContentManagement` role in your `Web.config`. For testing analytics locally you will need to use the `Standalone` role:

```
<add key="role:define" value="Standalone" />
```

Comment: I am getting this error on the ContentManagement server. I don't want to change it to the Standalone as this one is actually a content management system.

Comment: @ArunKumar Why do you need session/tracking on a pure CM instance?

Comment: I don't need it. How do I disable it?

Comment: @ArunKumar dont enable tracking .Xdb.Tracking.Enabled to false